# Rename File to (First, Last) name using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have files that are named as ( Johnson, Peter file cleanup.pdf ) I like to know if renaming this file to just (LastName, FirstName.pdf) is possible using vba. I have multiple files and this would need to be done to all of them, none of which is the same name. is this possible? LET ME MAKE MYSELF CLEAR, I AM AWARE FILES CAN BE RENAMED, I AM TRYING TO RENAME MULTIPLE FILES DIFFERENT NAMES example below

```
EX-
ABC.PDF - JOHNSON PETER.PDF
EFG.PDF - BROWN LISA.PDF
HIJ.PDF - WILSON BETH.PDF
```

once i rename file there should also be a subfolder created with this file then placed in it

this is my code for folder creation

```vb
Sub CreateFolder()
    
    'Variable declaration
    Dim sFolderPath As String
        
    'Define Folder Path
    sFolderPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Macro Testing\PdfFolder"
        
    'Check Specified Folder exists or not
    If Dir(sFolderPath) <> "" Then
        'If folder is available
        MsgBox "Folder already exists!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
         
    'If folder is not available
    MkDir sFolderPath
         
    'Display Message
    MsgBox "New folder has created successfully!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
    
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. What helpful info have you found with your favorite search engine, e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=rename+files+vba?

Comment: BigBen asked a reasonable question.  Google is great for this type of problem - use it *first*, then ask here if you have problems with what you find.  The first hit from that link literally tells you exactly what you need to do.  `Replace(fileNameHere, " file cleanup.pdf", ".pdf")` would give you the name you need.

Comment: i have already exhausted google, i am 100% clear on the capability of files  being renamed, what im trying to do in specific has not been answered in none of the links i've clicked and tried, reasons why i came here, knowing i was going to get chewed up but im not just renaming files im renaming multiple files different names and am trying to automate this process using VBA, im new to the language and i decided to seek some guidance but yall clearly cant assist without the sarcasm